# Having trouble getting my POST request to work properly

Tags: javascript, json, express, post, postman

I am trying to make a test post request to mongo db. In Postman I received this error:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Post validation failed: photo: Path `photo` is required., body: Path `body` is required., snippet: Path `snippet` is required., title: Path `title` is required."
}
```

[image: This is what I have in Postman.]

This is a screenshot of Postman.

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    snippet: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    photo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
}, { timestamps: true });

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

This is my Schema.

```
router.post("/add-story", upload.array('photo', 10), async(req, res) => {
  try{
    let post = new Post();
    Post.title = req.body.title;
    Post.description = req.body.description;
    Post.photo = req.body.photo;
    Post.snippet = req.body.snippet;

    await post.save();

    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: "Successfully saved."
    });
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: err.message
    });
  }
});
```

This is the POST request.

I tried taking the "required: true" off and the request went through successfully and created an empty entry into my database.

Comment: Are you using Multer middleware? (http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)

Comment: Yes. I don't know for sure if I'm using it correctly? This is my first time using it.  But that's in my post request where I'm uploading an array of photos.  I tried putting single too but that didn't change anything.  Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your body type from `x-www-form-urlencoded` to `form-data` and see if it works:

Like in the following picture: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to post multiple photos, *Up to 10 photos?.* Your `photo` property on your `postSchema` should be an array. You should set it

```
// ...
photo: {
    type: [String], // have multiple images
    required: true
},
```

And the route `/add-story` would be like,

```
router.post('/add-story', upload.array('photo', 10), async (req, res) => {
    const photoPath = [];
    req.files.forEach(file => {
        photoPath.push(file.path);
    });

    req.body.post = photoPath;
    const post = new Post(req.body);
    try {
        await post.save();
        return res.json({
            status: true,
            message: "Successfully saved."
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
    }
});
```

The array of photos come as binary data from the request and can be accessed as `req.files`.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a typo error.

I had:

```
let post = new Post();
    Post.title = req.body.title;
    Post.description = req.body.description;
    Post.photo = req.body.photo;
    Post.body = req.body.body;
    Post.snippet = req.body.snippet;
```

but needed:

```
let post = new Post();
    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.description = req.body.description;
    post.photo = req.body.photo;
    post.body = req.body.body;
    post.snippet = req.body.snippet;
```